# Exiting go applications gracefully

Tags: go

I'm new to Go and I have a few small services running.

When I'm deploying a new version, I typically just upload the new binary, `kill` the existing process and start a new one.

I'm wondering if this is the correct thing to do, or if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: What are your goals? There's nothing wrong with what you're doing, and there's nothing really different for a Go program vs any other.

Comment: @JimB I'm just making sure that it is actually ok. I imagine for example many HTTP services would finish handling any outstanding requests before exiting. `kill` feels wrong, but that might just be my inexperience.

Comment: Like others said, kill-and-restart isn't that uncommon (in Go or elsewhere). There is some code that goes out of its way to avoid dropping connections at restart: https://github.com/facebookgo/grace

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in killing the process, replacing and restarting. If you want to do some cleanup on exiting you may do following:

```
import(
   "fmt"
   "os"
   "os/signal"
   "syscall"
)

func main(){
   //work here

   go gracefulShutdown()
   forever := make(chan int)
   <-forever
}

func gracefulShutdown() {
    s := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(s, os.Interrupt)
    signal.Notify(s, syscall.SIGTERM)
    go func() {
        <-s
        fmt.Println("Sutting down gracefully.")
        // clean up here
        os.Exit(0)
    }()
}
```

If you do kill {pid} (without -9 switch), process will call `gracefullShutdown` function before terminating.

Comment: Better way without blocking `main()` indefinitely: https://play.golang.org/p/X-6_qY810j.  No reason to fire `gracefulShutdown()` in a goroutine when it's going to light another one anyway, and this lets **main** be the one to actually end the program (which is what should be happening).  Also, in your version, forever doesn't actually have to be run through `make`, as a nil channel blocks indefinitely.  Thus `var forever chan int` avoids an allocation and works the same way.